# How Spark's OrderBy work under-the-hoods?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wish to better understand the under-the-hoods and performance implications of global ordering vs within-partition ordering.

Global ordering is achieved by:

```scala
df.orderBy("sortKey")
```

While within-partition is achieved by:

```scala
df.repartition("key").sortWithinPartition("sortKey")
```

Both `orderBy` and `sortWithinPartitions` implement the `sortInternal` private method, "only" changing locallity:

```scala
  def sortWithinPartitions(sortExprs: Column*): Dataset[T] = {
    sortInternal(global = false, sortExprs)
  }

  def sort(sortExprs: Column*): Dataset[T] = {
    sortInternal(global = true, sortExprs)
  }

  def orderBy(sortCol: String, sortCols: String*): Dataset[T] = sort(sortCol, sortCols : _*)

  private def sortInternal(global: Boolean, sortExprs: Seq[Column]): Dataset[T] = {
    val sortOrder: Seq[SortOrder] = sortExprs.map { col =>
      col.expr match {
        case expr: SortOrder =>
          expr
        case expr: Expression =>
          SortOrder(expr, Ascending)
      }
    }
    withTypedPlan {
      Sort(sortOrder, global = global, logicalPlan)
    }
  }
```

source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1321

When comparing the two physical query plans for a contrived `df`, we get:

```scala
scala> val df = Seq(Person("p1", 1), Person("p2", 2)).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: bigint]

scala> df.repartition(col("name")).sortWithinPartitions("age").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Sort [age#10L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#9, 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [plan_id=22]
      +- LocalTableScan [name#9, age#10L]

scala> df.orderBy("age").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Sort [age#10L ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(age#10L ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=11]
      +- LocalTableScan [name#9, age#10L]
```

The above makes clear that the only difference in terms of physical planning is the partition strategy.

1. What are the performance implications of them two? (which implies in how much effort should I put in modeling my data to make use of within-partition ordering, instead of global ordering)
2. How Spark know the exact global ordering if data is still partitioned (by range)?
3. Are there any other Spark's internals we should take into consideration when choosing between the two approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: `orderBy` makes a preliminary job of getting statistics on the data, that's how it knows how to partition it. You don't see this job in the plan (`explain`). `repartition().sortWithinPartitions()` is pretty straightforward

Comment: Thanks. The getting stats job is probably for the partition by range part, right? What about the other questions?

Comment: I guess my comment can answer 1 and 2 - the performance implication of `orderBy` compared to `repartition().sortWithinPartitions()` is mainly the stats job. As for 3, you get totally different results from each method. It's not a question of performance, it's a question of the requirement (global vs local sorting)

Comment: There is no good or bad option. They are different use cases and do completely different things. The choice depends on what you will do next with the DF.

Comment: There is something I don't get with this question. `repartition().sortWithinPartitions()` does not yield a sorted dataframe. What is the point of comparing it with `orderBy`?

Comment: I might need to improve the answer. The repartition.sortWithin gets you data sorted per partition. Sometimes the requirements give you the trade-off of how much to put effort in avoiding global ordering. If you have this trade-off, how would you consider it?

Comment: I see this is stated in the first question. If you have a suggestion on how to improve clarity, please do it. :)